# How to plot something in Kibana if it is unique to today?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have some data in ES coming via LS. I want to plot this in Kibana such that for today I see only data that is 'abnormal.' I only want to get the data if it is anomalous or has not occurred previously.

These messages contain many logs and I am working on filtering out the noise. What I really want to do is to plot any logs that are unique today vs. each of the past several days. So, if I have three days, day 1, day 2 and day 3, if today is day 3 and a log message contains 'A', and 'A' was also in day 1 and day 2, I do not want to aggregate and count the number of occurrences of 'A'. If, however, a message is 'B', and 'B' happened on day 1 but not day 2, I do want to count the number of occurrences of 'B' on day 3. Of course if 'C' has happened on day 3 and not on day 1 or day 2 I want to count and plot that.

More formally: How can I create an Elasticsearch query that I can use in Kibana to count the number of occurrences of a message type that has not appeared in all of the N days prior?

If we're talking about pseudocode it would be:

`Select * FROM document_today WHERE any_daily_past_count = 0`

I think using SQL I could get this done with a table within a table selection but I am not sure where to start with Elasticsearch queries.

If querying for whether `'C' has happened on day 3 and not on day 1 or day 2` is easier than 'B' on day1 and not day 2, but on day 3 I will be fine with that.

Comment: What is the logic you are trying? It sounds like `non_consecutive` occurrences? isn't?

Comment: That sounds like it, but for today and grouped by days. I'll do some research and see if I can answer this (as well as try to come up with a more concrete example). thanks.

Comment: Sure. And if you already have an index let us know the structure of it. Or a plan also. Because that ll help in providing precise answer.